# How can I add a gradient inside this triangle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website but am having a little trouble adding a gradient into triangle shape I have created in css.

Here is what I am trying to go for:

[Figma Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A5Kq.jpg)

However here is what I have right now

[Actual Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYg45.png)

```css
.triangle-tl {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 1000px solid black;
  border-right: 2000px solid transparent; 
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-tl"></div>
```

What Can I do to add a gradient into this triangle?

Comment: you seem to have copied the image OK - look at their css to see how they do it?

Comment: I made this markup website on a design website but I'm trying to transport that over into HTML if that helps

Comment: Yes it did, I just had to use the clip-path polygon. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clip-path CSS property to do that.
to get a basic understanding click [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_clip-path.asp)

And if you want to go for a specific clip-path design (geometry).
yu can easily make it with [This.](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)